# Flutter/Dart - How to force override a getter & setter or any method in a class that is extending an abstract class?

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

**Scenario:**

For example, I have the following abstract class `Synchronizable`:

```dart
abstract class Synchronizable {
  /// Getter & setter for sync status of the current data
  bool get synced;

  set synced(bool status);

  /// Method that will be called to execute the synchronization process
  Future<Either<Error, dynamic>> onSync();
}
```

As you can see the class has 3 different abstract methods:

1. Getter for `synced` bool value
2. Setter for `synced` bool value
3. An abstract method `onSync` to perform synchronization

I have extended the class in one dummy implementation for this question:

```dart
class DummyImpl extends Synchronizable {

}
```

The IDE gave me an error/warning to must override abstract methods, but the method count was not `3`, **it was `2`.**

[image: Prompt to implement abstract methods]

When I implemented using the prompt, It overrode only `2` methods.
The `getter` & the `onSync` method.

[image: Auto complete to override abstract methods]

**Note:**
The error is gone from the class name, meaning the override was successful & did not miss any method to override.

**Question(s):**

1. How do I force override of the `setter` method in this case?
2. Why is the compiler skipping the `setter` for the override?
   **(Not important but curious about this)**

**Update:**

From the responses I got, It seems that getter/setters are replaced with a member directly by the compiler. However the main question still remains unanswered, how do I force override the any methods.

To reflect the same intention, I have updated the Question title as well. Please respond to solve that part.

Thank you.

Comment: The `bool synced` member implicitly creates a getter *and* a setter, so both will be overridden.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a getter *and* a setter will allow you to do this:

```
instance.synced = true; // calling setter
```

and

```
print(instance.synced); // calling getter
```

It seems the shortest solution to provide this abilities to your class is to do exactly what your compiler did:

```
@override
bool synced;
```

You can set it. You can get it. Both don't do any additional work. But that is not what `abstract` enforces anyway. It just enforces it to be overriden, you cannot keep a derived class from doing nothing when overriding your methods. You cannot *force* anybody to actually put code in there.

Your constraints were satisfied. The derived class has a getter and setter for `synced`.

Answer (score -1):

Because your setter has the same name the getter.
So basically, the compiler skip the setter after overriding the getter.
You can change the name of your setter.

Comment: Can you provide any documentation/link that mentions this kind of behavior? 
I'd like to know why the getter & setter were converted to a member.

Thanks for the answer, though.